# how to configure each pods/process consume different kafka topic partition

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka topic that has 5 partitions. I have 5 pods currently consuming these 5 partitions. However due to a particular need, I need each pod to only consume from its assigned partition. But due to pods all having the identical configuration on kubernetes I can't tell each pod which partition to consumer. What's the best way to achieve this? Should I just have 5 independent deployments instead?

That seems odd with all 5 having the same code. I've seen the use of stateful set, but that seems to rely on an index. Not sure how robust that approach is.

Comment: Are all of the replicas running with the same Kafka consumer group name?  The Kafka broker should allocate partitions between the consumer pods; you shouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: What is the scenario to do it manually!?

Comment: @DavidMaze , In  my case I have 5 different producer and cosumer , In that case how can i distinguish the POD for each topic

Comment: @Manuel Have you get any update on it, please help me on the same

Comment: @casualprogrammer Any solution on this seniro , I have need to do the same , please help me on it

Comment: Kafka will ensure that only one consumer in the consumer group is reading from each partition and you don't especially need to do anything here.  It's not guaranteed to perfectly balance the load across consumers (I might increase the number of partitions if possible) but I'd expect the default setup would work for you here.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze for the prompt repsponse . I have one question like that I have a microservice in that i have 5 different consumer like A,B,C,D,E from different producer like  A1,B2,C1,D1,E1. But My question is that I want 5 pods/process (kubernetes) which should have differenent topic like for pod 1 -->> A-A1 , pod2 --> B->B2 and so on pod 5--> E-->E1 . Is it fisible , please help me on it

Comment: If that's really the workflow you need then I'd probably set up five separate topics, but I'm not clear why you'd need the producers and consumers to be at once so bound together and so separated from their other replicas.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Take a look on my post, if this helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to change your deployment to a statefulset, each pod of your replica will contain a sequence number starting from 0. The podname is fixed like my-kafka-consumer-0, my-kafka-consumer-1, my-kafka-consumer-(N-1), and so on.

Next you should use the podname as an environment variable inside your pod which can be read by your application.

You can do it by set the env variable like this:

```
env:
  - name: MY_POD_NAME
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.name
```

If this is done, your application should be able to read this information from the environment variables. This is needed to identify a consumer inside the consumer group.

So the next thing what you're looking for it's called a static membership in your kafka client configuration.

You can reach this by setting the group.id and the group.instance.id

```
'group.id': 'consumer-group'
'group.instance.id': '<MY_POD_NAME FROM THE ENVIRONMENT VARS>'
```

Not tested, but i think this should do the trick.

Comment: One more thing to add. It's still able that one pod crash/stuck/disconnect which probably leads to a rebalancing and could cause that on consumer get two topic partions. If you want to to reduce this balancing you can raise the session.timeout or implement a custom paritition assignment strategy.